# Putting raster values in polygons ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, attribute-joins, zonal-statistics

I'm trying to extract values from a raster file dataset (called land_use) to polygons (in a file called Hydro_buff) that I have created.
I read a few questions on that topic but some other issues come up.

I have tried "zonal statistics" but I get a raster output when I just need a feature output. So I tried using "zonal statistics as table" to then join the two tables together (join to Hydro_buff) but it doesn't work because for some reason I go from 74 034 polygons to just 31 426 after using zonal statistics as table so  lot of the polygons have Null value. All of my polygons have a UID that I created using the "create Unique ID" tool.

I checked the extent of both of my files and only 10 000 polygons don't overlap the land_use

Does anyone know what the problem is ?

Comment: Some of your polygons have no single cell centre inside.

Comment: Could you explain what this means and if there is a way to fix this ?

Comment: It means your cell size is too big for some polygons, try to reduce it.

Comment: is it possible even if only 100 polygons are smaller than 5m and my cell size is 2m ?

Comment: It might also mean that you buffers overlap.